# Bigquery YTD WORKDAYS calculation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I use the below calc to calculate workdays in a month.
i.e for calendar date = 28-05-2021 , i get 23 days ( monday to friday)

```
(select count(*) from unnest(generate_date_array(date_trunc(CALENDAR_DATE, month), last_day(CALENDAR_DATE, month ))) day
where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7)) as Workdays_Month,
```

I would like to calculate YTD Workdays based on the Calendar Date
i.e
if calendar date = 28-05-2021 then YTD workdays would be sum of workdays in months ( Jul 20 to May 21) financial year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your financial year starts in July - you can use below

```
select count(*) 
from unnest([struct(extract(year from current_date) as year, extract(month from current_date) as month)]),
unnest(generate_date_array(if(month < 7, date(year - 1, 7, 1), date(year, 7, 1)), last_day(date(year, month, 1)))) day
where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7)
```